# EF Code First exception The entity type is not part of the model for the current context using Simple Odata client

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

I have three classes `User` , `Role` and `UserRole`.

Using Code First I have created tables like below

```
DbContext.cs
rotected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<CodeFirstDBContext>(null);

    modelBuilder.Entity<DomainModels.Security.User>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<DomainModels.Security.User>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

              modelBuilder.Entity<DomainModels.Security.Role>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<DomainModels.Security.Role>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);


// UserRoles table column names as UserId and RoleId instead of default created by ER as User_Id and Role_Id.
            modelBuilder.Entity<DomainModels.Security.User>().HasMany(x => x.Roles).WithMany(y => y.Users).Map(
            of =>
            {
                of.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                of.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                of.ToTable("UserRoles");
            });
}

 public virtual DbSet<DomainModels.Security.Role> Roles { get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<DomainModels.Security.User> Users { get; set; }
```

Not Added `UserRole` DbSet as it is created by EF in many to many relations

My issue is, that when I try to perform any CRUD operation on `UserRole` it throws an exception:

> The entity type UserRole is not part of the model for the current context
>   We are using `simple odata`

```
 var resul = await odataclient.For<UserRole>().Set(new { UserId = userId, RoleId = roleId }).InsertEntryAsync();
```

I'm not sure whether `Simple OData Client` supports this or not.
What should I do?

Comment: Did you update the database?

Comment: yes i have updated database successfully !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have setup is so called many-to-many relationship with auto "link" table maintained for you by EF. In such configuration `UserRole` **entity** does not exist. The model should be something like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties
    // ...

    // UserRole association
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties
    // ...

    // UserRole association
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

You perform CRUD on *UserRoles* table by using either one of the navigation properties `User.Roles` or `Role.Users`.

**EDIT:** Alternatively, you can keep the `UserRole` entity and use explicit link table with two `one-to-many` associations like this:

**Model:**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties
    // ...

    // UserRole association
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // other properties
    // ...

    // UserRole association
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext:**

```
 public virtual DbSet<DomainModels.Security.Role> Roles { get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<DomainModels.Security.User> Users { get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<DomainModels.Security.UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
```

**Configuration:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DomainModels.Security.UserRole>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });

modelBuilder.Entity<DomainModels.Security.UserRole>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.User)
    .WithMany(y => y.UserRoles)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();

modelBuilder.Entity<DomainModels.Security.UserRole>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.Role)
    .WithMany(y => y.UserRoles)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.RoleId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

With this configuration you can use your original CRUD design.

Comment: thanks a lot but we are using Simple  Odata client for insert / update how to use it?

Comment: I don't get the question. How to use what?

Comment: I have update my question in detail , previously we are directly using `UserRole` model and using simpleOdata Client we can direct insert/update/delete, now as we are using EF `many-to-many relationship with auto "link"` we can not use direct `UserRole` it gives exception. i'm n ot sure wether simple Odata client supports this or not

Comment: Updated the answer with alternative EF model which I guess allows you to keep your `UserRole` CRUD design.

Comment: previously we did the same what you suggested, we don't need to add this ` public virtual DbSet<DomainModels.Security.UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
` because we are using `many-to-many relationship with auto "link" table` 
instead of using DbSet is it possible to do so ?

Comment: No. You either use "auto link" approach and change your CRUD somehow (no `UserRole` entity), or keep the CRUD with `UserRole` entity and setup two `one-to-many` associations. There is no third option.

Comment: ` change your CRUD somehow` means what ? unable to do it using simple Odata

Comment: I'm not familiar with OData, all we are discussing here is the possible EF models and how you can perform CRUD operations. For instance, adding `UserRole` in the second model is equivalent of `userRole.User.Roles.Add(userRole.Role)` or `userRole.Role.Users.Add(userRole.User)` in the first model if the `User` and `Role` objects are correctly populated from the database.

Comment: yes thanks Ivan , created new question with more details for odata please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561269/insert-update-data-to-many-to-many-entity-framework-how-do-i-do-it

Answer (score 2):

*Many-to-Many* table in *EF* isn't available as physically accessible entity, rather you have to perform operations on it using either of the involved entities, as the related entity is available as `ICollection` in both of the models. *EF* doesn't expose this entity rather manages it internally.

*i.e, You must have* `ICollection<User> Users` *as navigation property in *`Role` *and vice versa.*

Let's say, you have an object of `User`, and you need to get/set role against it. You will have to do it as:

```
User user = GetSomeUser();
Role adminRole = GetAdminRole();
user.Roles.Add(adminRole);

Role role = user.Roles.Where(x => x.Id == adminRoleId).firstOrDefault();
```

Above example is just give you understanding of how to work with `Many-to-Many` relationship in *EF*