# Insert/Update data to Many to Many Entity Framework . How do I do it?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, odata

My context is =>
[image]

Using this model via  Entity Framework code 1st, 
data table in database becomes =>

1) User Table

[image]

2) Role Table

[image]

3) UserRole Table -  A new linked table created automatically

[image]

Model for User is =>

[image]

Model for Role is =>

[image]

and my O Data query for inserting record for single  User/Role table working properly

[image]

Now, what query should I write, when  I want to Insert record to UserRole table

can someone have any idea

Comment: The point of EF (being an ORM) is to abstract away the database and let you deal with *objects* instead of tables/rows/columns. That's why you don't have to ask yourself "How do I `INSERT` into `UserRoles` table?" but rather "How do I associate a new `Role` with a `User`" and now the answer is much clearer: `user.Roles.Add(role)` or `role.Users.Add(user)` (EF knows that both of the latter statements are 2 ends of the same relationship so they're effectively the same)

Comment: how do i use it using simple Odata client ?
when I want to add new user i did like following
await metadataManagementClient.For<User>().Set(new User {Id= new Guid(),Name='Test'}).InsertEntryAsync();

Now How do I associate a new Role with a User? please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Fetch the user.
var user = await metadataManagentClient.For<User>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name == "Test");


// If you want to add a new role.
var newRole = new Role()
{
    Name = "My new role"
};
user.Roles.Add(newRole); // Adds new role to user.

// If you want to add an existing role
var existingRole = await metadataManagentClient.For<Role>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name == "My Existing Role");
user.Roles.Add(existingRole); // Adds existing role to user.

// Save changes.
metadataManagentClient.SaveChanges();
```

Or

```
await metadataManagentClient.SaveChangesAsync();
```

You might want to set ID as well. But watch out for `new Guid()` since it generates an empty guid. What you probably want (if you're not using IDENTITY) is `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Comment: simple Odata client do not have any methods like `SaveChangesAsync` and `SaveChanges`